# ng-include vs. ui-view for static content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

I'm populating my index.html via angular, as per usual. I have an index that looks something like:

```
<body>
  <nav ng-include="'app/partials/navbar.html'" ng-controller="NavBarController"></nav>
  <main>
    <section ui-view="donate"></section>
    <section ng-include="'app/partials/about.html'"></section>
    <section ui-view="stories"></section>
    <section ng-include="'app/partials/contact.html'"></section>
  </main>
  <footer ng-include="'app/partials/footer.html'"/>
</body>
```

My `nav`, about, contact and `<footer>` all have static content, so I used `ng-include`. The donate and stories `<section>`s are dynamic, so I used `ui-view`.

### The Question

Is there any advantage to using `ui-view` over `ng-include` where static content is concerned? The `nav` might be better with a `ui-view` I can reference the `NavBarController` in `$stateProvider.state()`, but what about the static partials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ui-view` is useful only when you want to leverage the feature of browser history. For e.g. If you have a HTML as below

```
<div class="searchbar">
    <input type="text" ng-model="student.id">
    <button type="button" ng-click="getStudent()">Get Student</button>
</div>
<div class="student-info">
    <div class="student" ui-view="studentview"></div>
</div>
```

Having a `ui-view` here will make sense since we can pass different data (like student id etc) as parameter to the same template and display different content. Also the browser history will help us navigate between different students here.

For content like **about** or **footer** though which are mostly static I would **recommend you to use ng-include** as you are hardly getting anything extra out of router here.

For **Contact** it can depend on what it contains. If it is something which requires navigation (like one route for contact of each country's office) then go with `ui-route` otherwise stick with `ng-include`